# How can I connect to DynamoDB table with Java Application and insert items into it

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write a JAVA application to connect to DynamoDB table and insert the item into it. I couldn't find the proper notes on how to do that. 
The application is a maven project . 
I need the guidelines on how to do it .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AWS documentation with Java samples at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html is the latest.